# CMAKE 3.9.3 Cannot Find Boost1.65.1 Boost_Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake, boost-python

it's kind of very daunting now. I've tried all I could possibly figure out, to no avail.

I am using ElementaryOS Loki, based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
I have `boost 1.65.1` installed under `/usr/local`
I am using `cmake 3.9.3` which is supporting building boost 1.65.0 and forward.

I have tried every possible way to mess with my `CMakeLists.txt`, which as of now, looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR )
project( boostpythondemo )

set( Boost_DEBUG ON )

MESSAGE("Boost Debugging is on.")

set( Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE )

if( Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
    set( BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/boost_1_65_1" )
    set( BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/usr/local/boost_1_65_1/boost" )
    set( BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/usr/local/boost_1_65_1/stage/lib" )
endif( Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS )


find_package( PythonLibs 3.6 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

find_package( Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED )

if( Boost_FOUND )
       MESSAGE("******************************BOOST FOUND*******************")
endif( Boost_FOUND )

include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )

add_library( heyall SHARED heyall.cpp )

add_library( heyall_ext SHARED heyall_ext.cpp )
target_link_libraries( heyall_ext ${BOOST_LIBRARIES} heyall )
set_target_properties( heyall_ext PROPERTIES PREFIX "" )
```

from the [command line output](https://codeshare.io/5M9AzJ) I can see I am setting the boost variables to the correct locations.

However, cmake just can't find boost_python. I really can't figure out what's going on now. the line says "BOOST FOUND" never got printed.

here is also the full [cmake output log](https://gist.github.com/stucash/5297f5c03fb447ab89cb119b25e39979).

I built boost with python 3.6.2 which will be used to build boost_python as well, so this way I can use python 3 against boost_python.

Anyone has bumped into this before?

Comment: any help is much appreciated. I've spent more than a day now. like full day.

Comment: What is the full path to the `config.hpp` inside your Boost installation?   What is the full path to the `libboost_system.*` library?

Comment: thanks John. the config.hpp is under `/usr/local/boost_1_65_1/boost/config.hpp`. all the libs are under  `/usr/local/boost_1_65_1/stage/lib`

Comment: OK, then your Boost include dir should be `/usr/local/boost_1_65_1/` instead.   Can you try that?

Comment: I just tried it, I did `set( BOOST_INCLUDEDIR  "/usr/local/boost_1_65_1/" )`, I still got the same failure. I tried without the forward slash at the end as well.

Comment: What is the full path to your `boost_python` library?

Comment: it is `/usr/local/boost_1_65_1/stage/lib/libboost_python3.so`, and I have `libboost_python3.so -> libboost_python3.so.1.65.1` as well.

Comment: What if you say `find_package( Boost COMPONENTS python3 REQUIRED )`?  Note the 3.

Comment: @stucash I am experiencing the exact issue with `boost 1.65`

Comment: @JohnZwinck it worked! sorry I was too tired yesterday. i knew it'd be something very obvious while I was so blind! thanks a lot John!

Comment: @James hey James it turned out I only had to change to python3 to make it work. but thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @JohnZwinck for pointing out the obvious over-looked error I had and @James for sharing his answer. but it seems his answer is for Boost 1.63.0, so I wanted to post a solution here so anyone who's having problem with latest CMAKE and Boost Python (up to today) can save some head scratching time.

some prep work first, so go ahead download CMAKE 3.9.3, please beware that if you are using Boost 1.65.0 or above, you will need to use at least CMAKE 3.9.3, CMAKE explicitly bundles with different Boost versions and 3.9.3 is the one shipped with 1.65.0 or above.

Otherwise, you may get an error from CMAKE saying

> imported targets not available for boost version

**Install Boost 1.65.1 (with python3.6.2)**

download Boost 1.65.1 and extract it under `/usr/local`

you can just follow Boost official guide (getting started guide) to install boost with python2, it should be hassle-free.

but to install boost with python3, you will firstly need to add a user-config.jam file and specify the python version you want to use to build Boost (Boost Python). You will need to specify the parameter on command line like James did (`./bootstrap --with-python=Python3`), and add an user-config.jam in your home directory.

firstly, you should create a user-config.jam under your `/home/$USERNAME/` (a subdirectory of `/home`). You can specify your compiler (gcc, clang, etc), and some other stuff, and for us it is the python version.

to create a user-config.jam, you can do

`$ sudo cp /usr/local/boost_1_65_1/tools/build/example/user-config.jam $HOME/user-config.jam`

inside your user-config.jam file, add this line:

`using python : 3.6 : /usr/bin/python3.6 : /usr/include/python3.6 : /usr/lib ;`

replace with your python 3 version.

now we are building and installing Boost 1.65.1

`$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local --with-python=python3`

`$ ./b2 --install -j 8  # build boost in parallel using all cores available`

once it's finished make sure you in your `.profile` add:

`export INCLUDE="/usr/local/include/boost:$INCLUDE"`

`export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH"`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

**Setting up CMAKELists.txt**

The one in the question details works just fine; but once you have followed the above steps, a simple CMAKELists.txt like below should suffice.

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR )
project( boostpythondemo )     

find_package( PythonLibs 3.6 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

find_package( Boost COMPONENTS python3 REQUIRED )

if( Boost_FOUND )
        MESSAGE("********************************FOUND BOOST***********************")
endif( Boost_FOUND )           

include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )

add_library( heyall SHARED heyall.cpp )

add_library( heyall_ext SHARED heyall_ext.cpp )
target_link_libraries( heyall_ext ${BOOST_LIBRARIES} heyall )
set_target_properties( heyall_ext PROPERTIES PREFIX "" )
```

Apparently the BOOST_FOUND message was for debugging you can safely remove it.

now you should just go ahead build using `cmake` & `make`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some dependencies for both CMake and Boost, so I am removing my old answer and providing a link to the bash script on GitHubGist.

The script can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/JamesKBowler/24228a401230c0279d9d966a18abc9e6)

To run the script first make it executable

```
chmod +x boost_python3_install.sh
```

then run with sudo.

```
sudo ./boost_python3_install.sh
```

enjoy!

Comment: it looks like you are using Boost 1.63.0, according to your link above. I am using 1.65.1 and I fixed it by switching to python3. the fix mentioned in above seems not required anymore in newer version of Boost, at least in 1.65.1. but thanks for sharing.

Comment: @stucash the download link points to Version 1.65.1 which is what I am using. The instructions link is for 1.63 however, this seems to work for me.

Comment: for me I don't have to fix the bug which should only be in 1.63.0, 1.65.1 works without it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, James!