# Can't install bob package by pip

Tags: python, boost, boost-python, python-bob

I am on Windows 7 with python 3.6. I am trying to install bob package by typing `pip install bob` in the command window. But I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\azhidinov_37005\AppData\Local\Programs\boost_1_66_0\boost_1_66_0\libs\p
ython\example\quickstart>C:\Users\azhidinov_37005\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\
Python36\Scripts\pip.exe install bob
Collecting bob
  Using cached bob-3.0.0.zip
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\azhidinov_37005\appdata\lo
cal\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from bob)
Requirement already satisfied: bob.extension==2.4.5 in c:\users\azhidinov_37005\
appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from bob)
Collecting bob.blitz==2.0.14 (from bob)
  Using cached bob.blitz-2.0.14.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\AZHIDI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hpictomi\bob.blitz\se
tup.py", line 70, in <module>
        system_include_dirs=system_include_dirs,
      File "c:\users\azhidinov_37005\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\
site-packages\bob\extension\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
        boost_pkg = boost(boost_req.replace('boost', '').strip())
      File "c:\users\azhidinov_37005\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\
site-packages\bob\extension\boost.py", line 69, in __init__
        raise RuntimeError("could not find boost's `version.hpp' - have you inst
alled Boost on this machine?")
    RuntimeError: could not find boost's `version.hpp' - have you installed Boos
t on this machine?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AZHIDI~1
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hpictomi\bob.blitz\
```

After that I downloaded boost from here http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_66_0.html
Unziped and built it. Then built separetely boost.python. Now I have all of them in root directory. But when type `pip install bob` stil get the same error. I think python can't locate the boost directory. What should I do? Please help!

Comment: This seems like a similar post. Might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374747/cmake-3-9-3-cannot-find-boost1-65-1-boost-python

Comment: @Orenshi Thank you for your comment. But it is about building boost. I built already my boost. But pip cannot find **version.hpp** in boost/ subdirectory, although it is there. I think I need somehow explicitely say the pip to look inside the boost/ subdirectory for **version.hpp**, but don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

or 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.53.0/

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/install

> Bob does not work on Windows and hence no conda packages are available
>   for it. It will not work even if you install it from source. If you
>   are an experienced user and manage to make Bob work on Windows, please
>   let us know through our mailing list.

There is already some effort to make Bob work on Windows:

- https://github.com/bioidiap/bob.extension/pull/1
- https://github.com/bioidiap/bob.blitz/pull/1
- https://github.com/bioidiap/bob.core/pull/1

If you are interested and experienced, you can contribute.